# FileUploadBase does not find any multipart parts when uploading small files

Tags: java, spring, servlets, file-upload

I am using Spring's `CommonsMultipartResolver` to process file uploads in a servlet 3 environment.

If the uploaded file is large, everything works fine.

If the uploaded file is smaller, the resolver fails to discover any parts (with no exception thrown).

I have tracked this down to `apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemIteratorImpl` for which the `findNextItem()` method returns false, despite there being multiple valid parts in the post. This results in no `MultipartFile` object being available to my controller method.

When I look in the debugger at the `HttpServletRequest` I see the correct number of parts (`getParts()` returns the correct number of parts).

I could just use the `HttpServletRequest`, except that for large files (>1MB), an exception is thrown about the maximum file size (which I have successfully configured for the `CommonsMultipartResolver` but evidently does not cross over to `HttpServletRequest`).

I looked at attempting to configure the Servlet 3 maximum file size, but I don't want to add several new classes to my application only to set that size.

Is there a way to upload smaller files using Servlet 3 and `commons-fileupload`?

**More**

I have `commons-fileupload` configured as `maxUploadSizePerFile`=100MB.

The following behavior results:

If the uploaded file is > 10MB, then `commons-fileupload` processes it and everything is fine.

If the uploaded file is between ~3.8 MB and 10 MB, both the input stream and the underlying connection are closed before `commons-fileupload` has a chance to parse the request leading to a connection reset message in the browser.

For uploaded files between 1 MB and ~3.8 MB, the input stream is closed, but not the underlying connection, allowing my error page to display the error.

And finally, if the uploaded file is less than 1 MB, the underlying servlet 3 implementation successfully handles the parts before `commons-fileupload` gets invoked, leaving `commons-fileupload` believing that there were no parts in the request.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this is totally caused by spring boot jumping in the way and trying to help you out, which in this case causes problems. Here are the steps to fix it:

Configure CommonsMultipartResolver as a bean (more than likely you already did this):

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

Disable spring servlet multipart handling in your application.properties file

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=false
```

Then rejoice with great enthusiasm.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior results from using Spring Boot which (previously unbeknownst to me) automatically configures multi-part for Servlet 3. This causes the underlying `HttpServletRequest` to process the file upload before `commons-fileupload` has a chance at it.

The only thing that I find curious at this point, is why it does not fail if the uploaded file is large enough.